# Is the Projection Matrix estimated using least-squares pose specific?

Tags: computer-vision

I am calibrating a camera and estimating the projection matrix using the least-squares technique described [here](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558/19-cameracalibration.pdf).

So far, I thought that the projection matrix that I got with this method was invariant, e.g., I could use it disregarding if the camera was moved or not.

However, I have been doing some additional reading, and I came across a [set of slides](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/courses/vfx/05spring/lectures/handouts/lec07_calibration_4up.pdf) that led me to believe that, if the camera is moved, then I'd have to estimate the projection matrix all over again.

Can someone please clarify this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  If you move the camera, the projection matrix changes.

However, fortunately you don't have to start from scratch.  If you know the new position of the matrix relative to the old one, you can adjust the projection matrix.  Or, if you don't know how the camera has moved, you'll need to re-estimate the extrinsic parameters, but the intrinsic parameters will remain unchanged (the projection matrix is the composition of an intrinsic matrix and an extrinsic matrix, and only one depends on the camera's position).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning.

Comment: How are you able to answer any question about any topic D.W. ?!